# How to type hint an object of unknown child class, but known parent class?

Tags: python-3.x, python-typing

This is Python 3.10. My code is as follows:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Union

class Vehicle():

    def __init__(self, components):
        self.components = components

    def getComponentWithFlag(self, flag: str) -> Union[Component,None]:
        for component in self.components:
            if getattr(component,flag,None):
                return component
        return None


class Component():
    pass


class PassengerComponent(Component):

    def __init__(self):
        self.carriesPassengers = True

    def ejectPassenger(self):
        print('A passenger is tossed outside!')


class FreightComponent(Component):

    def __init__(self):
        self.carriesFreight = True


VW_Mini = Vehicle(components= [PassengerComponent()])
VW_Passat = Vehicle(components= [PassengerComponent(), FreightComponent()])
Truck = Vehicle(components= [FreightComponent()])

assert VW_Mini.getComponentWithFlag('carriesPassengers')
assert not VW_Mini.getComponentWithFlag('carriesFreight')
assert Truck.getComponentWithFlag('carriesFreight')
assert not Truck.getComponentWithFlag('carriesPassengers')

component = VW_Mini.getComponentWithFlag('carriesPassengers')
component.ejectPassenger()
```

Last line gives me a warning in PyCharm: `Cannot find reference 'ejectPassenger' in 'Component | None'.` I understand why it happens: there is no `ejectPassenger` method in Component class. Clearly the problem lies in how I typehint `Vehicle.getComponentWithFlag` method. Could you guys tell me how I should type hint its return object?

I know the object returned by that function:

- may be None (if there's no appropriate Component),
- may be an object of a subclass inheriting from `Component` class,
- will never actually be an object of `Component` class itself.

Type hinting it explicitly like this: `def getComponentWithFlag(self, flag: str) -> Union[PassengerComponent, FreightComponent, None]` will not fly, because I will eventually have dozens of Components in my actual use-case and I would prefer to avoid typing them all out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I would prefer to avoid typing them all out.
```

Unfortunately, I don't think it is possible, as you can't exclude root type only. (i.e. You can't hint all subclasses of `T` without `T`, as `T` is also subclass of `T` in static typing)

Instead, you can overload `Vehicle.getComponentWithFlag`.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Optional, Literal, Union, overload

class Vehicle():

    def __init__(self, components):
        self.components = components

    @overload
    def getComponentWithFlag(self, flag: Literal["carriesPassengers"]) -> Optional[PassengerComponent]:
        ...

    @overload
    def getComponentWithFlag(self, flag: Literal["carriesFreight"]) -> Optional[FreightComponent]:
        ...

    def getComponentWithFlag(self, flag: str) -> Union[Component, None]:
        for component in self.components:
            if getattr(component,flag,None):
                return component
        return None
```

Try this code in your IDE. This code has limitation that you have to maintain overloaded variants as number of subclasses increases. However, I think this is optimal for now.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would there be an easier way if I implemented `Component` as an abstract base class with `abc`  module (which it is, by the way, but I've just learned about them)? Is there a way to typehint `getComponentWithFlag` method return value with 'whatever_implemented_Component_ABC'?

Comment: 1. I don't think `abc` will help out.
2. I don't understand your question.